# Грамматическая основа (2)

Tags: синтаксис

Преподаватели русского языка и просто люди, которым это интересно! Во время поиска теории наткнулся на примерно такое:

> Погода если и будет хорошей, то недолго.

Теперь возник следующий вопрос: будет ли "недолго" являться однородным именным сказуемым по отношению к "будет хорошей"? Мне кажется, что двойной союз соединяет два однородных именных сказуемых (читал у Розенталя, что двойные союзы используются для соединения однородных членов): "будет хорошей" и "будет (продержится) недолго".
Объясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Погода если и будет хорошей, то **(будет хорошей/такой)** недолго.*

Двойной союз действительно соединяет  однородные именные сказуемые, но вторая его часть относится к пропущенному однородному члену (к нему в качестве распространителя относится наречие ***недолго***).

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое!

Comment: Спасибо Вам за интересный вопрос.